# Component props not working to fetch data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I have a component that must display some data from the api. I am making the request from the parent page but the loop is happening in the child component. But data are not showing in the parent page.

I am getting this error: **Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "listObject". Expected Object, got String with value**

Is there any possibility of moving the nested API request in the child component?

**Child component code **

```
<template>
    <div class="mt-2 mb-2">
        <h3 class="mb-0"><strong>{{listTitle}}: </strong></h3>
        <ul class="lists">
          <li v-for="list in listObject" :key="list.url">
            {{ list.name }}
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            listTitle: String,
            listObject: Object
        }
    }
</script>
```

Parent component

```
<template>
    <div v-if="movie.speciesData.length">
    <h1 class="movie__card-title card-title text-center">{{ movie.title }} </h1>
        <Lists listTitle="Test" listObject="movie.speciesData" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
import Lists from '@/components/Lists.vue'
export default {
  name: 'MovieDetails',
  components: {
    Lists
  },
  data(){
    return {
      movie: {
        speciesData: [],
      },
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get('https://swapi.dev/api/films/'+this.id)
      .then(response => {
        this.movie = response.data;

        // Fetch species data for each species URL
        const speciePromises = this.movie.species.map(specieUrl => axios.get(specieUrl));

        // Wait for all specie data requests to complete
        Promise.all(speciePromises)
          .then(specieResponses => {
            this.movie.speciesData = specieResponses.map(response => response.data);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });

      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

See this line in your parent component:

```js
        <Lists listTitle="Test" listObject="movie.speciesData" />
```

You are passing a string to listObject, you are not binding it to vue data.

You can use v-bind here:

```js
        <Lists listTitle="Test" v-bind:listObject="movie.speciesData" />
```

Comment: This approach worked but it is taking longer for the data to load. I tried it before.

Comment: The time to pass data between components is negligible. There might be something more going on. Just check how much time the network calls are taking to fully complete. Ideally you shouldnt be making so many network calls at all.